# hide row by using sql query if all cell values of row are zero than hide that particular row

Tags: mysql

`where '0' NOT IN (I_DET_FACTOR1, I_DET_PERC1, I_DET_FACTOR2, I_DET_PERC2, I_DET_FACTOR3, I_DET_PERC3)`

I am using this query any one zero than hide total row .but my requirement is all are zero than only hide total row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide row when **any** column is zero (show row when **all** columns are **not** zero)

```
WHERE 
    I_DET_FACTOR1 <> '0' 
    AND I_DET_PERC1 <> '0' 
    AND I_DET_FACTOR2 <> '0'
    AND I_DET_PERC2 <> '0'
    AND I_DET_FACTOR3 <> '0'
    AND I_DET_PERC3 <> '0'
```

To hide row when **all** columns are zero (show row when **any** column is **not** zero)

```
WHERE 
    I_DET_FACTOR1 <> '0' 
    OR I_DET_PERC1 <> '0' 
    OR I_DET_FACTOR2 <> '0'
    OR I_DET_PERC2 <> '0'
    OR I_DET_FACTOR3 <> '0'
    OR I_DET_PERC3 <> '0'
```

Comment: above your solution is showing records are zero  they show remaining are hide but my requirement is hide all are zero than show remaining records

Comment: above one  i am using any one zero the total row are hiding but my case all are zero at that time only total row are hide. I_DET_FACTOR1 ,I_DET_PERC1 ,I_DET_FACTOR2 ,I_DET_PERC2 ,I_DET_FACTOR3 ,I_DET_PERC3 for above columns any one zero the total row are hiding but my case all columns zero only the row are hide

Comment: @M.Nagendra You want to hide row when all columns are zero, right?

Comment: thank u so much its working i am using or condition its working